# SQL SELECT query output with specific format

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need, if possible, a T-SQL query that will return the values in a specific format from the columns.

I can do this programmatically (c#), but is it possible to do in query using SQL Server 2008 ?

Here's the current query

```
select id, server_name, domain_name 
from mastertable
```

Current output:

```
id server_name   domanin_name
1  sys1          one.abc.in
2  sys2          two.pqr.in 
3  sys3          three.abc.in 
4  sys4          four.xyz.in
```

I need to display data as (skip value after (.) for column domain_name):

```
id server_name domanin_name
1  sys1        one
2  sys2        two
3  sys3        three 
4  sys4        four
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT id, server_name, SUBSTRING(domain_name, 1, CHARINDEX('.', domain_name) - 1)
FROM mastertable
```

Comment: Works - as long as you're **sure** that `domain_name` will always contain a `.` - if that's not the case, your query will fall flat on its nose (*Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.*) ...

Comment: @marc_s But if the field is "domain name", then is it a valid domain name in the first place if it doesn't contain a "."? But in any case, you make a valid point.

Comment: Yes - I would assume, too, that such a column would include a `.` - but I'd rather **check** to make sure, rather than just *assume* ... (principle of defensive programming)

Comment: SELECT id, server_name, SUBSTRING(domain_name, 1, CHARINDEX('.', domain_name) - 1)
FROM mastertable
this give one., two.
DID LIL EDIT
SELECT id, server_name, SUBSTRING(domain_name, 0, CHARINDEX('.', domain_name) - 1)
FROM mastertable

Comment: Curious, because starting from zero doesn't work for me (end up with "on", "tw", etc. Are you sure you had the -1 after the char index?

Comment: @MiikaL. sry my mistake****
SELECT id, server_name, SUBSTRING(domain_name, 0, CHARINDEX('.', domain_name) )
FROM mastertable

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    server_name,
    mod_domain_name =
        CASE CHARINDEX('.', domain_name)
            WHEN 0 THEN domain_name
            ELSE SUBSTRING(domain_name, 1, CHARINDEX('.', domain_name) - 1)
        END
FROM mastertable
```

This tests to make sure there's a `.` in the `domain_name`, and if so, it "clips" the domain name to show only the bits before the first `.`